# How is the standard error calculated for the `lambda.1se` output in the cv.glmnet function?

Tags: r, lasso, ridge-regression, glmnet, elastic-net

I understand that `lambda.1se` is the largest lambda that gives MSE within one standard error of the minimum MSE. But how is the standard error calculated exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default parameter settings `grouped = TRUE` and `nfolds = 10`:

The training dataset is separated into 10 folds. For each fold, the data in the remaining 9 folds are used to fit models for a range of $\lambda$ values. The error measure (e.g., deviance, MSE) is computed on the observations within the fold, for each value of $\lambda$. This yields 10 accuracy measures for every value of $\lambda$. The standard deviation over these 10 values for each value of $\lambda$ is the standard error.

Comment: Ok, so you calculate the standard deviation over the 10 values which are the sums of residuals that you get from each fold.  
And not the standard deviation of all of the separate N residuals.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, assuming a continuous response variable. Minor note: residuals are squared before summing. If you specify grouped = FALSE, you get the SD of the N separate squared residuals, divided by sqrt(N).

Comment: So for your original answer should we be dividing this standard deviation by sqrt(10).

Comment: No. A standard error (SE) of a statistic is the standard deviation of its sampling distribution (or an estimate of it). So if you compute the standard deviation over a distribution of the estimated statistics (grouped = TRUE), that standard deviation is already the standard error. The grouped = FALSE approach takes the standard deviation over N squared errors. To turn this into a standard error for the mean squared error, one needs to divide that standard deviation by sqrt(N). Note that both approaches generally yield very similar, but not identical SE estimates.

Comment: Ok, so when you say "The error measure (MSE) is computed on the observations within the fold". Then how is the final MSE chosen in the output is it just the mean of these 10 values.

Comment: Yes, that is correct!